# EQ Db/Amplitude Tracking

Tags: audiokit

I am new to AudioKit for iOS, I have tracked the maximum amplitude of 63Hz equalizer of a sound and I changed the gain value of it to 0 using `AKEqualizerFilter` class. It's successfully changed and I can listen it but I want to know how can we display that change in the form of amplitude/dB/Gain using AKFrequencyTracker class?

here is my code which changes the gain value of 63Hz sound.

```
var filterBand3 = AKEqualizerFilter(
    filterBand2, centerFrequency: 64, bandwidth: 70.8, gain: 0.0).
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

First step, I record a song using iPhone microphone, in parallel I am tracking highest amplitude of EQ 63 Hz band. here is the code of my first controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {

        let tape = try AKAudioFile()

        player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: tape)

        let mic = AKMicrophone()
        micCopy1 = AKBooster(mic)
        micCopy2 = AKBooster(mic)            
        micCopy3 = AKBooster(mic)            
        let mixer = AKMixer(player, mic)            
        tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mixer)           
        recorder = try AKNodeRecorder(node: mixer, file: tape)          
        AudioKit.output = tracker           
        try AudioKit.start()           
        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.005, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    } catch {

        AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")

    }
}

@objc func runTimedCode()
{
    print(“Amplitude :: ", tracker.amplitude)
    print(“Frequency :: ", tracker.frequency)

    trackeddB1Slider.value = 0

    if tracker.frequency > 62 && tracker.frequency < 110 {
        if tracker.amplitude > maxAmpValues {
            self.lable1.text = String(format: "Max:  %0.3f ", tracker.amplitude)
            maxAmpValues = tracker.amplitude

        }
        trackeddB1Slider?.value = tracker.amplitude
    }
}

@IBAction func startRecordungActoin(_ sender: Any) {
    if recorder!.isRecording {
        recorder!.stop()
        gameTimer.invalidate()
    } else {
        do {
            try recorder!.record()
        } catch {
            AKLog("Couldn't record")
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I set the gain value "0" of EQ 63 Hz for AKEqualizerFilter class and then i track the amplitude again for 63 Hz band.

My second controller class is here.

var tracker = AKFrequencyTracker()

```
@IBAction func startEQ(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        let player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: recordedAudioFile!)
        player.looping = true

        filterBand2 = AKEqualizerFilter(player, centerFrequency: 32, bandwidth: 44.7, gain: 1.0)
        filterBand3 = AKEqualizerFilter(filterBand2, centerFrequency: 63, bandwidth: 70.8, gain: 0.0)
        filterBand4 = AKEqualizerFilter(filterBand3, centerFrequency: 125, bandwidth: 141, gain: 1.0)
        filterBand5 = AKEqualizerFilter(filterBand4, centerFrequency: 250, bandwidth: 282, gain: 1.0)
        filterBand6 = AKEqualizerFilter(filterBand5, centerFrequency: 500, bandwidth: 562, gain: 1.0)
        let filterBand7 = AKEqualizerFilter(filterBand6, centerFrequency: 1_000, bandwidth: 1_112, gain: 1.0)

        tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(filterBand7)
        AudioKit.output = tracker
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
        }
        player.play()
        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.005, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    catch {

    }
}

@objc func runTimedCode()
{

    print(“Amplitude :: ", tracker.amplitude)
    print(“Frequency :: ", tracker.frequency)
    trackeddB1Slider.value = 0


    if tracker.frequency > 62 && tracker.frequency < 110 {
        if tracker.amplitude > NewMaxAmpValues[0] {
            self.lable1.text = String(format: "Max:  %0.3f ", tracker.amplitude)
            NewMaxAmpValues[0] = tracker.amplitude
        }
        trackedDB1Slider?.value = tracker.amplitude
    }
}
```

My Problem is, maximum value of amplitude remain same (Or some time grater) after applying AKEqualizerFilter with "0" gain value as before applying filter, I supposed that amplitude should be cut down for EQ 63 band.

I want to show the change in amplitude to client to prove that the equalizer is working fine.

Comment: If you are using a filter and would like to visualize that, you could use a tracker class, or an FFT plot, not really sure what you're trying to visualize.

Comment: I want to find out the change in amplitude before and after applying AKEqualizerFilter of 63 frequency band.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka please see my updated question above.